# HP multimedia keyboard 5209 support

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a keyboard with the HP logo on it, but when I try to get any info on it, it says model# 5209 & P/N 5187-3550 any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

HP, like any other OEM, sources their peripherals through a wide variety of vendor sources. Just because it has the HP tag on it doesn't mean HP made it. If you are looking for Linux driver support for the extra multimedia keys, Google search on the model #, part # and "Ubuntu". There's a very slim chance that HP *might* have a Linux driver for it, but I wouldn't hold out much hope on that avenue.